# compiler gives uninitialized local variable error despite initialized variable

Tags: c++, if-statement, initialization

I'm studying the *Declarations in Conditions* topics in C++ and faced the below problem.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  int x;
  std::cin >> x;
  if(int a = 4 && a != x) {
    std::cout << "Bug fixed!" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I declared and then initialized the variable `a`. In the *The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup Ed.2011*, it is said:

> The scope of variable declared in if statement extends from its point of declaration to the end of the statement that the condition controls.

That's what I did, I declared and initialized the variable `a`, but when I try to compare it against `x`, compiler gives `uninitialized local variable a used` error. Why, what's the problem?

I can do

```
int a = 4; 
if (a != x)
  // ...
```

but I would like to do it in one line if possible.

Comment: `if(int a = 4 && a != 3)` declares `int a` and then initialises it and in the initialisation uses `a` if I put brackets in (to match how the expression is parsed / evaluated) this should make it clear `if(int a = (4 && (a != 3)))`

Comment: @cigien thanks for your attention. First, I wanted to compare against x, input taken from command line . I made a slight mistake, wrote 3 instead of x. Never mind, It's not a big deal. I edited the snippet.

Comment: @Richard Critten I got it. then is there any way to write what I want to write? I want to write if statement condition in a way that it works.

Comment: The reason I didn't post an answer (and instead just explained the error) is I am not sure what you want to achieve with that line of code. If you could explain what you want then I will try and post an aswer.

Comment: I want to declare&initialize variable in the if statement condition and then use declared&initiliazlized variable for comparison in the same if statement condition. I wonder whether it's possible or not? For instance, consider this. 1) int a = 4; 2) if (a != 3) { cout << "Ok!" << endl; I want to write these 2 statements in the if statement condition part at once? Can we achieve this, any way?

Comment: @Alparslan can you explain what you are hoping the _logical and_ `&&` is doing?  Are you trying to test two things?  Are you familiar with what `&&` does?

Comment: If you look at @cigien comment above I think that answers your question.

Comment: I've clarified the intent based on the explanation in your comments (removing `x` was not the right suggestion, it's the 3 that's the problem). cc @RichardCritten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression inside the `if` condition

```
int a = 4 && a != x
```

what the compiler actually sees is

```
int a = (4 && a != x)
```

where the value of `a` is clearly being used before it's initialized (which is what the error is saying), and is not the intent of the code.

From C++17, you can use if-with-initializer syntax to achieve the effect you want

```
if (int a = 4; a != x)
  // ...
```